# following-sibling for any descendant confusion

Tags: xpath

For a html text

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">1</div>
  <div id="3">1</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I query

```
//following-sibling::div[3]
```

And the result is there

```
<div id="3">1</div>
```

But according to [XPath specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#axes)

> The following-sibling axis contains the context node's following
>   siblings, those children of the context node's parent that occur after
>   the context node in document order;

So what is the context node after that 3rd div is successfully found? It seems that when // founds first div, there's no 3rd div after it, the last accessible should be [2]. If the context node is not div but body or html then divs are not siblings for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context node is the first *text* node (containing only whitespace) in the `body` element.

Comment: It's interesting that by making // shortcut for descendant-or-self::node() and not descendant-or-self::*, they made it more universal, but now even if one has no interest in text() nodes at all (when for example text nodes has no affection on structure), there is implicit text() involving and texts in this case does affect structure interpretation.